# Sequelize - create recond with value that matches another table foreign key's value

Tags: node.js, orm, sequelize.js, nestjs

I have the following structure for Users_Role table:

```
| role_id(PK)    | role_name     |
| ---------------| --------------|
| 1              | Admin         |
| 2              | View          |
```

And the following structure for Users table:

```
| user_id (PK) | user_role_id(FK)    |
| -------------| --------------------|
| 12345        | 1                   |
| 22434        | 1                   |
```

The tables are connected by user_role_id and role_id
I want to create new records in Users Table, the thing is I only have the user_role value.

Is there a way to shortcut the way to get the value of the user_role_id, or the only way to do it is a seperate query before creating new record in Users?

```
const userRole = "Admin";

Users.create({
        user_id:"1234",
        user_role_id: ???
      })
```

Comment: that should be in a variable and come from the gui

Comment: I do have the user role value in a variable (edited above), what do you mean from the gui?

Comment: you first need to select from Users_Role the id and put it  into a variable and then use it in the create. usually you have a gui in which you select the rpöe and get the id  like a pull down or list

Comment: Yes I get what you mean, but let's say the id is secret, and I don't want to pass it to the client. The only possible way is to query it before the create query? or can I do in during the create query itself?

Comment: someone has an answer please?